# как подвинуть объект css?

Tags: html, css

Не двигается input text от радиокнопок

```css
.choice {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.multiplechoice {
    position: static;
}

input[type=radio] {
    right: 0;
    margin-left: var(--margin-left-right);
    margin-right: var(--margin-left-right);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

input[type=radio]::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--color-light-apricot);
    border: 2px solid var(--color-blue);
}

input[type=radio]:checked::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--color-blue);
    visibility: visible;
}

label {
    font-size: var(--font-size-label);
}

.scores {
    margin-left: var(--margin-left-right);
    margin-right: var(--margin-left-right);
}
```

```html
<div className={s.choice}>
    <div className={s.multiplechoice}>
    <label>
        <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />
        ...</label><br />
        <label><input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />...</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Score" className={s.scores} />
</div>
```

Comment: самый простой вариант - дать `label` или `input` (в зависимости от чего Вы делаете отступ) `display: inline-block`, т.к. и `label` и `input` - инлайновые элементы

Comment: @Meth0d не помогло. Подвинулось только, когда от label написала margin-right, но на нужное количество не подвинулось, а просто слетел текст вниз у радиокнопки

Comment: .scores {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
 помогло это, но это не лучший вариант

Comment: расскажите, пожалуйста, какое отношение имеет ваш вопрос к node.js?

Answer (score 0):

может так?

```
input[type="text"] {
   padding: 10px 0;
   margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: тоже почему-то не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

1. В сниппет вообще-то надо вставлять рабочий код, а не кусок с синтаксисом неизвестного фреймворка и с необъявленными переменными (поэтому ваши стиля не применяются к элементам в сниппете - классов нет, переменные неизвестны). А еще надо удалять то, что к вопросу не относится.
2. Вопрос надо формулировать так, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите. Куда не двигается? Как не двигается? Я, например, глядя на заголовок вопроса, первым делом подумал об анимации.
3. Ну и, собственно, все прекрасно сдвигается - вычистил ваш код и добавил цвета для наглядности. Инпут на расстоянии от лейблов и радиокнопок. Если не то, обновите, пожалуйста вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что вам надо:

```css
.choice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
}

.multiplechoice {
  position: static;
  background: yellow;
}

input[type=radio] {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background: green;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: wheat;
}

.scores {
  margin-left: 5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
  <div class="multiplechoice">
    <label><input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />...</label>
    <br />
    <label><input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />...</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Score" class="scores" />
</div>
```

Comment: извините, пожалуйста, я понимаю, что я новичок здесь, но не могли бы вы быть чуть вежливее?